# Is spring-security-saml project still actively developed?

Tags: spring-saml

Is the spring-security-saml extension still being developed/maintained? It has very good documentation and codebase but it looks like there is only one maintainer and recently all the activities has decreased. I mean the project looks like in a good shape, but it is based on older Spring releases and OpenSAML dependencies. I found other security frameworks (pac4j) being actively developed/maintained. Trying to determine if I can base a SAML 2.0 SP off the Spring project or i should go with something that is more actively maintained?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product roadmap question. Not a programming question.

Comment: Is there a forum where such questions can be asked? According to the project page the only forum is here. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll most likely find time to update the Spring + OpenSAML dependencies, but cannot commit to a precise date, time is scarce.

Comment: do you have plans to update OpenSaml to V3 as they have announced that V2 will EOL in July.  It appears to be non-trivial to upgrade and documentation for V3 of OpenSaml seems to be nonexistant.  Thanks for the great project!

Comment: I'll look into it soon. But the fact is that the v3 OpenSAML doesn't seem to support most of the stuff needed by SAML SP implementations. And OpenSAML 2 is stable. So one way is to include the missing parts of OpenSAML in Spring SAML's codebase directly.